# Understanding of this terrain intersection algorithm

Tags: algorithm, line, intersection, terrain, quadtree

I was looking for a fast way to get a ray intersection point of a terrain defined by a heightmap and I stumbled upon this: https://publications.lib.chalmers.se/records/fulltext/250170/250170.pdf

At part 3.2, I don't quite understand why would we get an intersection point in the beginning of the while loop since it starts with the first quadtree node which is basically the whole map thus there shouldn't be an intersection point with the ray (expect if the ray starts out of AABB, higher than the max height of the terrain but that is never the case for me).

Thank you very much if someone could make this thing clear.

Comment: The ray-AABB intersection routine probably just considers this case (i.e. the starting point of the ray is enclosed by the AABB) to be intersecting, as `t_far` in this case will be non-negative. In other words, it must be returning true if `t_near >= 0` or `t_far >= 0` rather than requiring that both `t_near` and `t_far` be non-negative.

Comment: Thank you, probably that is the case then :)